# In Swift, why does a bitwise NOT require adding one to get a positive integer's corresponding negative integer?

Tags: swift, binary

For example,

```
func challenge26c(subtract: Int, from: Int) -> Int {
    return from + (~subtract + 1)
}
```

Does the same apply in other programming environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to how integers are stored in Swift (and in almost every case I can think of), in what is called [two's complement notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). If you want a "positive integer's corresponding negative integer" (known mathematically as the *additive inverse*), you can simply use the unary minus sign `-` (for example, if `x` is 5, then `-x` becomes -5.

It looks to me like this is a challenge to implement subtraction without using `-`, though, so you probably will want to read up on two's complement notation.